# main body content is shifted to top when div is visible after clicking a button

Tags: jquery

I wanted to show div after clicking a button in magento.

code is

```
<div id="clickme" style="background-color: #333333; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 10px; width: 200px; cursor:pointer;">Click here to toggle me in and out</div>
 <div id="me"   style="display: none !important;"> <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footerbanner')->toHTML();?></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { $('#clickme').click(function() { $('#me').animate({
           height: 'toggle'
           }, 1000
      );
 });
});
```

Its working. But by this code footer is shifted but I want that Body content is shifted to top not footer. Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with your footer div,

```
<div id="footer" style='position:fixed;bottom: 0px;height: 40px;float: left;'>footer footer footer footer </div>
```

So, the footer will be displaying in bottom of the page always...

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jmvND/1/)

**EDIT :**
As per your requirement, just try this,

**HTML**

```
<div id="Content_div" style="height: 400px;">  
</div>

<div id="ja-botsl">
   <div class="main col4-set clearfix">
      <div style="height: 200px;" class="main-inner clearfix">
      </div>
      <span class='imgExpandSpan' id="ja-expand-trig">&nbsp;</span>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="footer_div" style="height: 100px;">
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .imgExpandSpan
    {
        background: url("https://bangalore/Ogo/Content/Images/arrow-green.png") no-repeat scroll center center #111111;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 30px;
        left: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        top: -29px;
        width: 60px;
    }
    .imgExpandSpan.expand
    {
        background-image: url("https://bangalore/Ogo/Content/Images/arrow-red.png");
    }

    #ja-botsl
    {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #111111;
        border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        color: #666666;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
    }
</style>
```

**JQuery**

you should use the given below plug-ins

[prototype.js](http://www.benarasisarees.com/js/prototype/prototype.js)

[ja.script.js](http://www.benarasisarees.com/skin/frontend/default/jm_scerif/js/ja.script.js)

Here is the [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/smanimani/5kFsh/)

Note : The script of `ja.script.js` have all our click event id's & expand inner div id. So we can able to change id's.,,

Comment: its not working properly. I want that after clicking button div of id me  with will overlap body content

Comment: now also footer is shifted but I want to shift body content. Please help me.

Comment: @user1465856: check now the above link, i think this one solve your requirement...

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I want effect like footer arrow in this website :----http://www.benarasisarees.com/. If You can help then please help me.

Comment: @user1465856 : so you want to show a arrow mark image in footer, when the user will click that arrow, we need to show the div with sliding options.. right?

Comment: ya I need that functionality. Please Help me